# Unable to get ifup & ifdown to bring up eth0 | Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, network-manager, ethernet

I'm trying to set up a static IP on a dual boot laptop ( Win10 and Ubuntu Studio 14.04). These are the settings:

sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address         192.168.1.101
    netmask         255.255.255.0
    network         192.168.1.0
    broadcast       192.168.1.255
    gateway         192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
    dns-domain example.com
    dns-search example.com
```

sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
#dns=dnsmasq
no-auto-default=54:04:A6:25:64:2E,
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

(there is a line space above and below "no-auto--")

The ifconfig returns the below:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 54:04:a6:25:64:2e  
      inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

      lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:312 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:312 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:29521 (29.5 KB)  TX bytes:29521 (29.5 KB)

      wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:92:9c:45:05:ae  
      inet addr:192.168.43.110  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::7a92:9cff:fe45:5ae/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2507 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1816247 (1.8 MB)  TX bytes:375757 (375.7 KB)
```

sudo ifdown eth0 returns

```
 `RTNETLINK answers: No such process
```

Any advice from pros what I should try to get it right? The targetted configuration is : eth0 up / internet connectivity while eth0 is up. I can post router and gui network manager settings.

sudo ifup eth0 elicits this response:

```
 `RTNETLINK answers: File exists
  Failed to bring up eth0.`
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try '=false' and restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Your `interfaces` file looks a bit busy; I'd amend it to:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
dns-domain example.com
dns-search example.com
```

Then try again:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: I de-indented the interfaces file, thanks. And No. The console had this to say : when I ran the second command :** ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
Configuring interface eth0=eth0 (inet)
run-parts --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
ip addr add 192.168.1.101/255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.1.255    dev eth0 label eth0
ip link set dev eth0   up
 ip route add default via 192.168.1.1  dev eth0 
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.**

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep eth0` ? As the result may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com What is the ethernet driver? Find it from `sudo lshw -C network` driver=??

Comment: Sorry I took awhile- had to boot back into windows after commands on the other OS. The 'networks' graphical symbol has completely vanished from the top menu. The pastebin is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23673821/

Comment: Ahhh! The infamous `r8169`! Please try: `sudo ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100` and then: `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0` Any change?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the r8169 driver part. (It wasn't easy with zilch connectivity). I downloaded stuff via windows and rebooted into ubuntu to config. The new driver shows up, but still no internet. Pastebin here, appreciate any further advice on whatever cranking I need to do to get eth0 up and running with access to internet.http://paste.ubuntu.com/23677673/ have a great holiday season!

Comment: Your `eth0` appears to be connected; it has the requested IP address.  May I assume that you've carefully checked the numbers? 192.168.1.1; not x.0.1, etc.? Can you ping the gateway? `ping -c3 192.168.1.1` If so, how about: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` ? With the newer driver, may we see: `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0` and: `sudo ethtool eth0` http://paste.ubuntu.com please.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23677963/ I'm risking moderator attention by ignoring the "avoid extended discussions.." warning - it isn't feasible to move to chat because I'd have to reboot between OS's to find the data you want to de-geek while you're waiting! Thanks for taking the trouble! Did I mess up in router settings- I've port-forwarded (http to port 80) to the eth0 IP?

Comment: See in the paste it says "Link detected: no"? I still think you'll have to: `sudo ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 100` to see a link. Check: `sudo ethtool eth0` We can automate the autoneg and speed if it works as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

A few things; MAC addresses in NetworkManager.conf should be lowercase, and you should remove the trailing ','. Given that you have stipulated the MAC of your wired interface as unmanaged you should also set:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

The format of your `interfaces` file looks ok.

Comment: Tried with both 'true' and 'false' - there's no connectivity - i need eth0 up and connecting to the net.